# Reverse complement of a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reverse

The `reverse complement` of a DNA sequence is formed by interchanging the letters `A` with `T` , `C` with `G` (and vice versa) as a first step, and subsequently reversing the entire anagrammed sequence. For example, the `reverse` of ACCTGAG is GAGTCCA (simply by reading the sequence from the end to the beginning), while the `reverse complement` is CTCAGGT (by interchanging the letters first and then reversing the resulted sequence).

How can I achieve the desired `reverse complement` output in SQL server? I provide the following SQL code for convenience.

```
DECLARE @seq NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @seq = 'ACCTGAG'

SELECT @seq AS [Sequence], REVERSE(@seq) AS [Reverse sequence]

---output---
Sequence    Reverse sequence
ACCTGAG     GAGTCCA

---Desired output---
CTCAGGT
```

Comment: What is your SQl Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.2)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here. HOw does `ACCTGAG` become `CTCAGGT` with your logic? Following the logic (`A` becomes `T`, and `C` becomes `G`) you get `'TGGTGTG'`. Then the reverse of that is `'GTGTGGT'`. As all the `A`'s have been replaced, how does your final string have an `A`? Why are there `C`'s when they too have been replaced?

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear. I edited my question. By saying interchange `A` to `T` and `C` to `G` I also meant that the same happens the other way round, e.g. `T` to `A` and `G` to `C` at the same time. So the `ACCTGAG` practicaly becomes `TGGACTC` and after the final reverse `CTCAGGT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with `TRANSLATE` and `REVERSE`:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(20);

SET @YourString = 'ACCTGAG';

SELECT REVERSE(TRANSLATE(@YourString,'ACTG','TGAC'));
```

`TRANSLATE` replaces each character in the second parameter with the character in the same ordinal position in the 3rd parameter. So for the above, `A` would be replace by `T`, `C` with `G`, `T` with `A` and `G` and `C`.

Importantly, as well, it will only process each character once, meaning that (for example), a character "translated" from `A` to `T`, will not later be translated back to `A` in the above expression. Nested `REPLACE` functions, however, would suffer that problem, so you would have to replace some with arbitrary characters first, and then replace them correct at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can use `replace()` a few times and `reverse()`:

```
select @seq,
       reverse(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@seq, 'A', 'B'
                                                                          ), 'T', 'U'
                                                                  ), 'C', 'D'
                                                          ), 'G', 'H'
                                                  ), 'B', 'T'
                                          ), 'U', 'A'
                                  ), 'D', 'G'
                          ), 'H', 'C'
                   )
          )
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13fd50b059eb6827095f71d487312701) is a db<>fiddle.

This replaces the bases with arbitrary letters and then puts them back to the reversed values.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `TRANSLATE` given you're using `SQL Server 2017`

```
DECLARE @seq NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @seq = 'ACCTGAG'

SELECT @seq AS [Sequence], REVERSE(@seq) AS [Reverse sequence]

SELECT REVERSE(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(@seq,'A','T'), 'C', 'G')) AS Translated
```

Though I agree with Larnu in his comment above. Your logic yields `GTGTGGT`. Unless we have misunderstood your request

Comment: There's no need for 2 `TRANSLATE` functions here. Only 1.

Comment: You are correct SELECT REVERSE(TRANSLATE(@seq, 'A''C', 'T''G')) AS Translated